# Разница между функциями findall и search

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Вопрос по регулярным выражениям Python, а точнее по функциям `findall` и `search`

Есть шаблон вида `pattern = re.compile(r'([aeiouy])\1{2}')`

Есть тестовая строка `str_1= 'hoooowe'`

Если я использую `re.search(pattern, str_1).group()`, то получаю значение `Match` объекта, т.е. 'ooo'

Логично предполагаю, что `findall` по тому же шаблону должен найти тоже самое, но в виде списка. Однако в результате я получаю не `list_1= [[ooo]]`, а `list_1 = [[o]]`.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Не называйте переменные `str`, `list` и т.п. -- это названия встроенных функций питона -- https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html :)

Comment: Это просто для наглядности, я и не называю

Comment: Вообще-то, методы для работы с регулярными выражениями всегда по умолчанию ищут непересекающиеся совпадения (`re.findall`, `re.search`, `re.finditer` - все так работают). Нет тут никакого пересечения в условии. См. правильное объяснение и примеры решений данной проблемы в [моём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/929221/182013).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В описании [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) есть такое описание:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
> strings.

Думаю поэтому у вас не нашлось как в `seacrh` - т.к. условие предполагает пересечение совпадений (в шаблоне у вас используется группирование).

Попробуйте вместо [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) метод [finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'([aeiouy])\1{2}')

text = 'hooooweee'

for m in pattern.finditer(text):
    print(m)
```

Результат:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 4), match='ooo'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 9), match='eee'>
```

---

**PS.**

Насчет `findall`, немного упростил регулярку, чтобы искались только последовательности гласных и она работает как ожидается:

```
items = re.findall('[aeiouy]{3}', 'hooooweee')
print(items)  # ['ooo', 'eee']
```

---

**PPS.**

Еще пример, в котором 3-мя группами выцепляем по одной гласной в последовательности по три подряд идущих символа.

И как мы видим `findall` в свой результат помещает, то что указывает в группе, в отличии от `search` и `finditer`:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'([aeiouy])([aeiouy])([aeiouy])')

text = 'hooooweie'

m = pattern.search(text)
print(m) # <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(1, 4), match='ooo'>
print(m.group(), m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3))  # ooo o o o

items = pattern.findall(text)
print(items)  # [('o', 'o', 'o'), ('e', 'i', 'e')]

for m in pattern.finditer(text):
    print(m.group(), m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3))

# ooo o o o
# eie e i e
```

поэтому для шаблона `'([aeiouy][aeiouy])([aeiouy])'` вернет `[('oo', 'o'), ('ei', 'e')]`

Answer (score 1):

Решение для данного случая ([демо](https://ideone.com/BfpkPI)):

```
import re
str_1= 'hoooowe'
pattern = re.compile(r'([aeiouy])\1{2}')
print([x.group() for x in pattern.finditer(str_1)])
# => ['ooo']
```

Дело в том, что `re.findall` возвращает только списки подстрок, захваченных захватывающими подмасками (группами), если таковые определены в шаблоне (если их больше одной, возвращаются списки кортежей с подстроками). Метод `re.search` (как и `re.match`) возвращает объект `Match`, который содержит собственный [набор методов](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), и получить доступ к целому совпадению можно с помощью `match.group()`.

См. [справку по `findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

Т.е. (в моём переводе) "если в шаблоне имеется одна или более подмасок, возвращает список групп; если шаблон содержит более одной подмаски, результатом будет список кортежей. Пустые совпадения будут также присутствовать в полученном списке, если они не граничат с началом другого совпадения".

**Чтобы `re.findall` возвращал только список совпадений**, обычно используется следующее:

- Удаление ненужных захватывающих подмасок (например, `(a(b)c)` -> `abc`)
- Замена захватывающих подмасок на **не**захватывающие (т.е. `()` -> `(?:)`) кроме случаев, как в ТС, когда в шаблоне присутствуют обратные ссылки, без которых регулярка не работает
- Использование `re.finditer` вместо `re.findall` (см. решение в начале ответа).